# scaling Entity Framework project that reads queue table

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-6

I have a windows service using Entity Framework 6.1 that reads from a Queue table.  I grab the oldest record with a status of **Pending**, then change the status to **InProcess**, when I am finished I change the status to **Complete**.

I need to allow for scaling.  I will have many of these windows services processing the queue table. There is a chance one instance will grab the oldest record after another has gotten it, but before it sets it to **InProcess**.  In this case, they will both be working on the same record.

I think I could do this with row locking but EF does not support that.

Any idea how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

I would call a stored procedure from EF that does this all in one shot.  Use a transaction to force a lock on the updated row.

Proc code sample:

```
DECLARE @myID TABLE (id INT)
BEGIN TRAN

;WITH orderCTE AS
(
    SELECT TOP 1 id,status
    FROM myTable T
    WHERE status='Pending'
    ORDER BY someDateValue ASC
)
UPDATE orderCTE SET status='inProcess'
OUTPUT inserted.id into @myID(id)

SELECT id
FROM @myID
COMMIT TRAN
```

Here is a functional example w/data:

```
DECLARE @test TABLE (id int, [status] varchar(100), someDateValue DATETIME)
INSERT INTO @test 
VALUES (1,'Pending', GETDATE())

DECLARE @myID TABLE (id INT)
BEGIN TRAN

;WITH orderCTE AS
(
    SELECT TOP 1 id,[status]
    FROM @test T
    WHERE status='Pending'
    ORDER BY someDateValue ASC
)
UPDATE orderCTE SET [status]='inProcess'
OUTPUT inserted.ID into @myID(id)

SELECT id
FROM @myID
COMMIT TRAN

SELECT * FROM @test
```